# Don't keep previously selected value in select box when page is reloaded

Tags: html, select

Deos anybody know how to prevent the browser from keeping the last selected option when the client reloads the page?

The problem is that when I reload the page, it keeps the last selected option, and when I select the url in the address bar and hit Enter it will be reset.

I want the second result whicth means that I want to get the browser always reset the select box.

Please the simplest and the safest way :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the value in javascript. That way when the page is loaded its always initialized to the same value. Just using `<option selected="selected">` won't work.

in javascript it would be something like this:

```
document.getElementById("selectBoxToBeReset").options[indexToBeSelected].selected = true;
```

and jquery helps even more:

```
$("#selectBoxToBeReset").selectOptions("value to be selected", true);
```

passing true as the second argument clears any previously selected value. [Jquery select box tips.](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/)

Answer (score 12):

The autocomplete="off" attribute works on select elements as well as on input elements:

```
<select autocomplete="off" >
     <option>1</option>
     <option selected>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, this is more correct.
Although the selected answer does work as well (no offence).

Comment: This is also the right choice when using React and fighting with browser selecting an option that doesn't correspond with the current state. Using JS to forcibly select an option in the DOM would mis-align the DOM and VDOM which React might not like so it's better to have use option.